# Ionic 5 Angular - Reactive Form inside of Ionic Modal

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms, ionic5

#### current State

I have a ionic tabbed app. One of the tabs opens a modal with multiple `<ion-input>`s.

#### What I expect to happen

To be able to use ReactiveForms to retrieve values of form fields in a modal. (First only to the modals module. The API will be called from the modals module)

#### What actually happens

Subscribing to the `valueChanges` of the FormGroup, the callback isn't called when typing into the inputs. The values also stay at their initial value/undefined;

**sidenote:** Even when supplying an invalid formGroup to the forms `formGroup`there is no error in the console. (Which would be expected)

#### My current code

```
import {ModalPage} from '...'
...
async presentModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalPage,
    });
    return await modal.present();
}
...
```

In this ModalPage's module I have imported the `ReactiveFormsModule`.

In the template I have multiple `ion-input`s

ex.:

```
<form [formGroup]="someFormgroup"
    <ion-item>
        <ion-input placeholder="Title" formControlName="someFormControlName"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

and in the matching .ts file I have `someFormgroup`:

```
ngOnInit() {
...
    this.someFormgroup = this.fb.group({
        meetName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
}
...
```

#### What I tried

I tried importing the reactiveForms module in both the modals page module and the tab its called from's module. I also tried switching to template driven forms wo/ success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you assigned the formGroup to the formControl-input of the form. The group should be assigned to [formGroup].

```
<form [formGroup]="someFormgroup">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-input placeholder="Title" formControlName="meetName"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

**EDIT:** Answer in Comments. Real issue was that the component shown in the Modal was not in the declarations of the Module that opens the Modal.

Comment: Also make sure that `formControlName` is correct. In your example, it's `someFormControlName` which the formGroup in your example doesn't have.

Comment: Oops, wrote that one out wrong for the question in a stroke of genius. Edited the question to accurately reflect the code

Comment: Did assigning [formGroup] to the form help?

Comment: Oh apparently not then, hmm.

Comment: Have you imported your component in the module that is producing the modal? Ie. in the component which hosts the component that has the `presentModal` function? It needs to be imported there so that also all the dependencies work.

Comment: @NgModule({ imports: [ MyModalComponentModule ]})
export class MyModalProducingModule { }
see what I mean?

Comment: Or if you don't live by the "one component per module" principle, then the module which has `async presentModal()` has to have your Modal Component in it's declarations.

Comment: And also in `entryComponents`, if you're using an older version of Angular (not 11+ IVY)

Comment: Thank you kind stranger, the issue was that I added the component to the imports rather than the declarations of the calling module